# Get age from date of birth with javascript and php

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying through a date that in js returns me the years and months that have passed, but I only get it to show me the days

```
$("#nacimiento").change(function(){
  
             
 var nacimiento=$("#nacimiento").val();
 var fechaInicio = new Date(nacimiento).getTime();
 var fechaFin    = new Date('<? echo date("Y-m-d");?>').getTime();

 var diff = fechaFin - fechaInicio;
 
var tiempo=diff/(1000*60*60*24);
         
         
  
 console.log(diff/(1000*60*60*24));

 document.getElementById('meses').innerHTML=tiempo;
         
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) package for this and create two `DateTime` objects and get the difference between them in Months from the `Interval` object and work from there.

eg

```js
const fromUser = DateTime.fromString(nacimiento)
const fromPhp = DateTime.fromString('<? echo date("Y-m-d");?>')
const diff = Interval.fromDateTimes(fromUser, fromPhp);

const diffMonths = diff.length('months')

console.log(diffMonths)
```

another approach without an external package might be just using `getMonth()` and `getFullYear()` example:

```js
const fromUser = new Date(nacimiento)
cnost fromPhp = new Date('<? echo date("Y-m-d");?>')
const months = fromUser.getMonth() -
    fromPhp.getMonth() +
    12 * (fromUser.getFullYear() - fromPhp.getFullYear())
```

Comment: I would like to do it without any external library... it is possible

Comment: just added a no-external-library example as well